# Adding background music on website

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, audio-player

I want to add a functionality on my website which will allow user to select music of his/her choice and it will play on my website. Following questions I have in my mind :-

**1. Moving to one page to another :-**

If user select suppose a.mp3 song and if he move to another page then that music will lost? Whether he have to start that music again ? I don't want to do that.

**2.Performance issue :-**

Playing a song on background will effect the website performance ? If yes how to improve the performance of website while playing a music on background.

**3.Music List :-**

I want user to select music of his choice, is this possible or I have to bring the list from a different website(music website) and then I have to show the list on my website.

I saw this [Background music in a php/html webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066475/background-music-in-a-php-html-webpage) and I like the answer of @VictorKilo but I want to know more on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow is about coding problems, your question doesn't meet the requirements.

Comment: @RST see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Still doesn't qualify.

Comment: @RST: It actually qualifies well. It doesn't need to be a "I have this code and I'm stuck" question. As long as it's a specific, answerable, programming problem, it's fine. This question does it just fine.

Comment: There is no question in here Google couldn't have found you the answer to. But I'll give it a rest.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

**1. Moving to one page to another**

In general yes, going from one page to the next makes the music start over, or at best (if you use javascript to keep track of where the user is in a song) the song will stop for a few seconds while the new page loads and then you can skip to where they left off.

There are a couple of work arounds but none of them are pretty.

1. You put your site in an iframe or frameset so whenever the user navigates in the frame only that part of the site loads so you can have part of your site not refresh
2. Convert all your links to ajax so whenever a user clicks on a link you use ajax to query the page and replace the main content div of your site with the data you retrieved from ajax
3. Have a pop up.  Most browsers block pop ups but if the user lets you you can have a separate window with your music

**2. Performance issues**

There aren't really any performance issues with music playing.  Browsers pretty much have it down great.  As far as I can think off the top of my head I can't think of any way to really improve performance.  Maybe reduce the quality of the .mp3 so it's smaller or change it to a newer format that's smaller?

**3. Music list**

Yes it's definitely possible to have a list of files that the user can choose from.  Streaming music from a different site is usually not allowed by the other site. You will have to check with them to see if they'll let you and if they will they may have an api or something that would help you with a way to list the music.  This question is a little too broad to answer on SO.  If you want help with creating a music selector try making one on your own (most likely a select box that has an onChange listener that then changes the source of the audio player) and if you can't make one on your own then post the code you've tried and people will be glad to help

**In general**

My personal opinion is I hate sound/music or ANY noise coming from any web pages.  Sometimes it bugs me so much I close the page and never go back.  The reason is, I have my favorite music or TV show that I'm already listening to and I don't want to be bothered by some site.  That is just my personal opinion but I imagine that it's a pretty widespread opinion since none of the popular sites (excluding music-centric sites like pandora, grooveshark, etc) have music playing in the background.

I hope all this helps you.

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply :). (1) I think I would go for your 2 point making my link to ajax. (2) I'll try to reduce the quality of mp3 player. (3) Yeah i'll try for listing the music and when user change the music it will play automatically. @chrislondon what I'm actually doing is to make a website more exciting I am adding this additional feature of playing music on background. So if user does not want to listen music he will not go to that section. Is anything else I will require to add this features so that it will not fail ?